# How to make these colored rectangles in HTML or Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

[Colored Rectangles Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMtdR.png)

Thank you for the idea!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at online example : i put span element (you can put also div or p or any other element , setup background color and add space char )

```html
<input type="radio" value="1"><span style="background-color:lime;">  &nbsp  &nbsp </span>Test</input>
```

In next example i use text like width parameter .

```html
  <input type="radio" value="1" style="width:20px;height:auto;" /> 
   <span style="background-color:lime;border:solid silver 2px;">Text in Rect   
   </span> Out of rect text
```

I use padding for rect size (width) but with out text in it!

```html
<input type="radio" value="1" style="width:20px;height:auto;" /> 
   <span style="background-color:lime;border:solid silver 2px;padding-left:100px">   
   </span> Out of rect text
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul>
  <li style="padding-bottom: 5px;display: flex;">
   <input type="checkbox">
    <i style="background:#FF0000;width: 18px;height: 18px;float:left;margin-
    right: 8px;opacity: 0.7;"></i> 
     <span>Red</span>
  </li>
  <li style="padding-bottom: 5px;display: flex;">
     <input type="checkbox">
     <i style="background:aqua;width: 18px;height: 18px;float: left;margin-
     right: 8px;opacity: 0.7;"></i> 
     <span>aqua</span>
  </li>
  <li style="padding-bottom: 5px;display: flex;">
    <input type="checkbox">
     <i style="background:brown;width: 18px;height: 18px;float: left;margin-
     right: 8px;opacity: 0.7;"></i> 
       <span>brown</span>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Later you can remove styling and put in separate css file.